# Custom page template not recognized with permalinks on

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

The custom page template shows up when I choose any permalink structure with an ID

> %post_id%

But after I change it to any other structure which does not have **post_id** in it my page defaults to the theme given in index.php.

Answer (score 0):

> Phew after an extremely lengthy investigation I have been able to
>   identify that this is direclty related to the fact I had a custom
>   taxonomy called "year". Year is already used by wordpress in the
>   permalinks and this was causing all the problems.
>
> I have now had to rename my custom taxonomy. So it is no longer year.

- I found a solution after a bit of searching around.
- This answer should be credited to wordpress.org member *[nicole2292](http://wordpress.org/support/profile/nicole2292)*